# Is this a shell sort or an insertion sort?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, sorting

I'm just starting to learn about sorting algorithms and found one online. At first i thought it was a shell sort but it's missing that distinct interval of "k" and the halving of the array so i'm not sure if it is or not. My second guess is an insertion sort but i'm just here to double check:

```
for(n = 1; n < num; n++)
{
    key = A[n];
    k = n;
    while((k > 0) && (A[k-1] > key))
    {
        A[k] = A[k-1];
        k = k-1;    
    }
    A[k] = key;
}
```

Also if you can explain why that'd be helpful as well

Comment: Well, let's see [shellsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort) and [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort)...

Comment: yeah i'm pretty sure its an insertion sort. Wikipedia's confusing as it gives me a lot of words that boggle my mind XD

Comment: It is indeed an insertion sort, look at the wikipedia animations and reason the code posted follows the same behavior. FWIW, an often overlook sort is [comb sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_sort).

Comment: @DeadMG, C or C++, how does that make a difference?

Answer (score 5):

[Shell Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort) consists of many insertion sorts that are performed on sub-arrays of the original array.

The code you have provided is insertion sort.

To get shell sort, it would be roughly having other `for`s around your code changing `h` (that gap in shell sort) and starting index of the sub-array and inside, instead of moving from `k` to `k-1`, you move from `k` to `k+h` (or `k-h` depending on which direction you do the insertion sort)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right, that does look a lot like an [insertion sort](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Insertion_sort).

<strike>This fragment assumes `A[0]` is already inserted.</strike> If `n == 0`, then the `k > 0` check will fail and execution will continue at `A[k] = key;`, properly storing the first element into the array.

This fragment also assumes that `A[0:n-1]` is already sorted. It inspects `A[n]` and starts scanning the array backward, moving forward one place every element that is larger than the original `A[n]` key.

Once the scanning encounters an element less than or equal to the key, it inserts it in that location.

Comment: It doesn't assume A[0] is sorted, A[0] is checked with A[k-1], k >= 1 (1 for first loop of n) ... the indices are offset -1 vs. the +1 from the canonical pseudo-code.

Comment: @pst, thanks for forcing me to take another look. Of course (as usual) you're correct -- I noticed the `k > 0` guard, but the failure case inserts the key into `A[0]` just fine.

Comment: @pst, it's insertion sort, so before case of `n=1` is applied, it assumes the array has only one element, namely `A[0]` and obviously an array with one element is always sorted.

Answer (score 0):

It's called insertion sort because the line `A[k] = key` inserts the current value in the correct position in the partially sorted array.